# Papa Parse and Leaflet: attempting to extract CSV files to use in webpage

Tags: html, leaflet, papaparse

I'm trying to use Papa Parse and Leaflet to read a csv file and display the points on a map. There are 6 categories in the csv: title, image, description, url, lat, lng. In that order.

Pretty new to HTML in general, but after several hours of searching I cannot figure out what is wrong with the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CSVExtract</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.4.1/papaparse.min.js" integrity="sha512-dfX5uYVXzyU8+KHqj8bjo7UkOdg18PaOtpa48djpNbZHwExddghZ+ZmzWT06R5v6NSk3ZUfsH6FNEDepLx9hPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>

  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    Papa.parse('my.csv', {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      complete: function (results) {
        results.data.forEach(function (row) {
          var marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.lng]).addTo(map);
          var popupContent = "<h3>" + row.title + "</h3>" +
            "<img src='" + row.image + "' alt='Marker Image'>" +
            "<p>" + row.description + "</p>" +
            "<a href='" + row.url + "' target='_blank'>More Info</a>";
          marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use a different software (csv parser) and got no results either. The map is being displayed, but the markers on the map are not.

Appreciate any advice on this.